# How does MVC routing understands the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

Global.asax.cs has the following code on initialization:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

What I'm asking is, how does it know that what it gets for "{controller}" will be the name of the Controller class to be invoked? Are there tokens defined somewhere? if so, can I list them?

If I define additional tokens (like "{lang}") will it assume they are additional parameters?

(I'm developing a custom URL rewrite/redirect handler, and I need it to work with MVC...)

What is the most practical way to define custom patterns and "aliases" for URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mvc runtime has the controller and action tokens hardcoded. In addition there is also "area" but thats about it.

Comment: got any links where I can read upon it, or is it "documented as code"?

Answer (score 1):

@TDaver If I define additional tokens (like "{lang}") will it assume they are additional parameters?

yes. If you define, for instance, a parameter like lang, it wil detect it. Think about like that, it will be the querystring field called lang of the page. and you can create a route for a pretyy url. Like below;

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

so the url will be like ; http://example.com/en/home/about

Also, the most important part of routing is to understand that the routes will be picked by order. for instance, if you have multiple routes matching your current request, the first route will be picked by MVC Framework.

I reccomend you to have a look at [phil haccked's RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Also you can create route constraints for advanced routing options as well.